Shortcut to specific file in eclipse
I have several projects in eclipse each having their own application.properties file.
I use 1 application.properties file frequently compared to the other 25 in my eclipse workspace.
I also do have several files named Application.java, ApplicationImpl.java etc.
Typing Applic in "Open Resource" and navigating thru 100 files is one way to reach the file.
Typing application.properties in "Open Resource" and navigating thru 25 files is one way to reach the file.
Is there a way to have a shortcut/favorite to a specific application.properties file such that I can go to the file with minimum effort?
All online solutions refer to "Open Resource"

Have you tried the Bookmarks View? Right click in the left-hand margin to add one to the file.

In the Open Resource dialog you can also specify the project or folder name, e.g. project_name/application.properties  will find all application.properties files that are contained in a folder or project named project_name (you can also use wildcards, e.g. *foo*/application.properties  for application.properties in a project/folder with a name containing foo). Be also aware of the menu File > Recent Files.

Create a symbolic link in the file system to the application.properties file that is important to you (probably right next to it). Eclipse will show you that link in the package explorer and other places where you see files in your workspace and you can open it like any other file not needing to change your habits. Let your revision control system ignore that symbolic link. You can choose whatever name suits you best for the symbolic link (except for the file extension so that eclipse still chooses the correct editor to open it).

That is exactly what the Bookmarks view is for.
Open the Bookmarks view and select the resource you want to add in the Project Explorer. Then use menu command Edit -> Add Bookmark... to add the selected resource to the bookmarks.
Once added to the bookmarks you can simply double click to navigate to the resource.
